# Query for boolean field as "not true" (e.g. either false or non existent)

Tags: mongodb

I'm sure I'm missing something very basic in MongoDB queries, can't seem to get this simple condition.

**Consider this collection**

```
> db.tests.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "name" : "Test1" , "deleted" : true}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "name" : "Test2" , "deleted" : false}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "name" : "Test3" }
```

I would simply like to query all the items that are "not deleted"

I know how to find the item that has a "deleted" flag set to true:

```
> db.tests.find({deleted:true})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "name" : "Test1" , "deleted" : true}
```

But how do I find all items that are NOT `"deleted"` (e.g. negate the above query, or in other words, any items that either doesn't have a `"deleted"` field, or have it with value `false`

**What I tried by guessing** (please don't laugh...)

```
> db.tests.find({$not : {deleted: true}})
```

(returns no results)

```
> db.tests.find({$not : {$eq:{deleted:true}}})
```

error: { "$err" : "invalid operator: $eq", "code" : 10068 }

```
> db.tests.find({deleted:{$not: true}})
```

error: { "$err" : "invalid use of $not", "code" : 13041 }

```
> db.tests.find({deleted:{$not: {$eq:true}}})
```

error: { "$err" : "invalid use of $not", "code" : 13034 }

What am I missing?

Answer (score 193, accepted):

```
db.tests.find({deleted: {$ne: true}})
```

Where `$ne` stands for "not equal". ([Documentation on mongodb operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/nav-query/))

Comment: According to the docs, using $ne doesn't appear to utilize an index - is there another solution that would be able to take advantage of an index? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/indexes/#using-ne-and-nin-in-a-query-is-slow-why

Comment: Just to re-iterate for other readers - *this query will not use the index*.  So pls don't use in production.

Comment: So what should be used in production instead?

Comment: @Juhana I just tested this with MongoDB 2.6.6 and it _does_ now use an index created for `{deleted: 1}`.

Comment: what would you do if a different kind of truthy value was used, such as the timestamp from when it was deleted?

Comment: Did not index correctly under 3.6.8 with compound indexes, but `$in: [false,null]` seemed to work.

Answer (score 42):

For the sake of completeness, another way to do this is with [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in):

```js
db.test.find({deleted: {$in: [null, false]}})
```

Including `null` in the array pulls in the docs where the `deleted` field is missing.  This query can use an index on `{deleted: 1}` in the current 2.6.6 MongoDB release.

Answer (score 8):

JohnnyHK has the best answer. The `$in` selector is the shortest and cleanest IMO.

This will test for exactly "false" or "non existent". And can be indexed.

```
db.tests.find({$or:[{deleted:false},{deleted:{$exists:false}}]})
```

An example with a use of an index.

```
((function(){
    print("creating collection 'testx' and inserting 50 trues, 50 falses, 50 non-existents");
    db.testx.drop();
    db.testx.ensureIndex({deleted:1});
    for (var i=0;i<50;i++){
        db.testx.insert({i:i,deleted:false});
    };
    for (var i=0;i<50;i++){
        db.testx.insert({i:i,deleted:true});
    };
    for (var i=0;i<50;i++){
        db.testx.insert({i:i});
    };
    var res0 = db.testx.find().explain();
    var res1 = db.testx.find({deleted:false}).explain();
    var res2 = db.testx.find({deleted:true}).explain();
    var res3 = db.testx.find({deleted:{$exists:false}}).explain();
    var res4 = db.testx.find({$or:[{deleted:false},{deleted:{$exists:false}}]}).explain();
    var res5 = db.testx.find({$or:[{deleted:true},{deleted:{$exists:false}}]}).explain();
    var res6 = db.testx.find({deleted:{$in:[false,null]}}).explain();
    print("res0: all objects                      ("+res0["n"]+" found, "+res0["nscannedObjects"]+" scanned)");
    print("res1: deleted is false                 ("+res1["n"]+" found, "+res1["nscannedObjects"]+" scanned)");
    print("res2: deleted is true                  ("+res2["n"]+" found, "+res2["nscannedObjects"]+" scanned)");
    print("res3: deleted is non-existent          ("+res3["n"]+" found, "+res3["nscannedObjects"]+" scanned)");
    print("res4: deleted is false or non-existent ("+res4["n"]+" found, "+res4["nscannedObjects"]+" scanned)");
    print("res5: deleted is true or non-existent  ("+res5["n"]+" found, "+res5["nscannedObjects"]+" scanned)");
    print("res6: deleted is in [false,null]       ("+res5["n"]+" found, "+res5["nscannedObjects"]+" scanned)");
})())
```

This should print

```
creating collection 'testx' and inserting 50 trues, 50 falses, 50 non-existents
res0: all objects                      (150 found, 150 scanned)
res1: deleted is false                 (50 found, 50 scanned)
res2: deleted is true                  (50 found, 50 scanned)
res3: deleted is non-existent          (50 found, 50 scanned)
res4: deleted is false or non-existent (100 found, 100 scanned)
res5: deleted is true or non-existent  (100 found, 100 scanned)
res6: deleted is in [false,null]       (100 found, 100 scanned)
```

Comment: When I do an explain on this query it shows the index is only used for the 'deleted:false' portion of the query.  The 'deleted:{$exists:false}' does not seem to use the index.

Comment: @emilebaizel $exists should available for indexing. Older versions of Mongo <2.5.5 may not have that feature. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10608

Comment: aha!  that's probably it.  we're on 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

For the case that someone needs this in an aggregation pipeline instead of `find`, this is what worked for me

```
db.getCollection('tests').aggregate([ 
  // ...previous operations...
  { $addFields: { "deleted_conclusion": { $cond: {
        if:{ $ne: [ "$deleted", false ]}, then: { $cond: [ "$deleted", ":TRUE", ":FALSY"]}, else: ":FALSE"
  }}}}
])
```

After adding the extra field you can go on with pipeline stages and have the information you miss

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking for mongoid syntax (I am using this in a rails app), this is what I came up with for a company's users:

```
2.3.1 :042 > accepted_consent = org.users.active.where(:accepted_terms_and_conditions => true).count
 => 553 
2.3.1 :043 > not_accepted_yet = org.users.active.where(:accepted_terms_and_conditions.ne => true).count
 => 6331 
2.3.1 :044 > 6331+553
 => 6884 
2.3.1 :045 > org.users.active.count
 => 6884
```